# XSLT: filter/group nodes in variables

Tags: variables, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to filter/group nodes in a variable.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
    <cell n="1"/>
    <cell n="2"/>
    <cell n="3"/>
    <cell n="4"/>
    <cell n="2"/>
    <cell n="5"/>
</row>
```

XSLT 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:element name="row">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>   

    <xsl:template match="cell">
        <xsl:variable name="attribute" select="@n"/>
        <xsl:variable name="sequence">
            <xsl:call-template name="seq">
                <xsl:with-param name="attribute" select="$attribute"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$sequence" group-by="cell/@val">
            <xsl:sequence select="."></xsl:sequence>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="seq">
        <xsl:param name="attribute"/>
        <xsl:element name="cell">
            <xsl:attribute name="val">
                <xsl:value-of select="$attribute"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Intended output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
    <cell val="1"/>
    <cell val="2"/>
    <cell val="3"/>
    <cell val="4"/>
    <cell val="5"/>
</row>
```

The XML-Code is just a example for a much more complicated File. What I want to do is process all the Elements `cell` first and save the result in a variable. In the second run I want to filter or regroup the nodes of the sequence.

I also tried to filter `$sequence` with predicates:

```
<xsl:sequence select="$sequence/*[@val != preceding-sibling::cell/@val]"/>
```

In this case the output-file is empty.

EDIT 2 (now it works):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="sequence">
        <xsl:for-each select="cell">
            <xsl:variable name="attribute" select="@n"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="seq">
                <xsl:with-param name="attribute" select="$attribute"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <row>
        <xsl:for-each-group group-by="@val" select="$sequence/*">
            <xsl:sequence select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="seq">
    <xsl:param name="attribute"/>
    <xsl:element name="cell">
        <xsl:attribute name="val">
            <xsl:value-of select="$attribute"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your example is not clear at all. If you want to process all `cell` elements first and store the result in a variable for further processing, you must do so from the context of `row` (or higher). I think that's about all that can be said at this point.

Comment: I tried to edit the earlier code, but now I'm not able to pass the `$attribute`. I'm afraid that my knowledge of XSLT finds its limits here.

Comment: Ditto Michael's comment -- it's not clear what you're trying to do.  I'd also add that your `$sequence` variable will only ever contain a single `cell` element, effectively a copy of the `cell` element that is the context for the match in `<xsl:template match="cell">`.  Since `$sequence` has only a single element, your attempt to filter `$sequence` using `preceding-sibling` fails.  To target more than one `cell` at a time, as Michael says, you need to start from the context of `row` or higher.

Comment: You need to start by explaining what exactly are you trying to accomplish here. And why is it necessary to do it in two steps.

Comment: Basically I want to filter a sequence which is saved in a variable. I am aware, that there are much easier ways to achieve the wanted output. I tried to make an example to illustrate that problem. Step1: Call a template and save the results in a variable. Step 2: Filter the outcome of Step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet that transforms `<cell n="x">...</cell>` into `<cell val="n">...</cell>` first and then groups those cell elements by the `val` attribute to eliminate duplicates:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="transformed-cells">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="cell"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$transformed-cells/cell" group-by="@val">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cell/@n">
        <xsl:attribute name="val" select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Output is

```
<row>
   <cell val="1"/>
   <cell val="2"/>
   <cell val="3"/>
   <cell val="4"/>
   <cell val="5"/>
</row>
```

http://xsltransform.net/a9Giwz

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid that my example wasn't that good. It is not about the intended output, but about to achieve the output, using a variable, which saves the outcome of a called template

Comment: Well, whether inside of the `xsl:variable` you use `xsl:call-template` (as you seem to want to do for reasons I don't understand) or `xsl:apply-templates` (as I have done in the example as it is the usual way in XSLT to process nodes) does not change the use of the variable in the `xsl:for-each-group` shown in my answer. So that answer should help in showing how to process the contents of the variable.

Comment: I want `xsl:call-template` because the stylesheet I refer to uses it. Anyway, your are right. I used `xsl:for-each-group` in a wrong way. Now it works all fine. Thanks.